# Is it okay to not use a constructor in a class?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have a class, which has some private static final fields (unsure if it is correct to call these constants), and one other instance variable set just private, which is  direct copy of one of the private static final fields.

Every time the object is created from other classes, I want it to have the same variables, as they are assigned in the class, and without creating a constructor, Java allows me access all of the methods with the correct returns as I would expect.

Is it okay to not create a constructor in this case?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but in Java an implicit no-argument constructor is automatically created for all classes that do not explicitly define their own constructor(s).

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two answers to your question:

1. It's fine not to include a constructor in your class. The Java compiler will add a default zero-parameters constructor for you.
2. It sounds like you shouldn't be constructing instances of your class in the first place. :-)

You've said

> Every time the object is created from other classes, I want it to have the same variables, as they are assigned in the class, and without creating a constructor, Java allows me access all of the methods with the correct returns as I would expect.

It sounds like you have roughly:

```
class TheClass {
    public final SomeType variable = /*...*/;
    // ...
}
```

...and you're doing this:

```
TheClass instance = new TheClass();
doSomethingWith(instance.variable);
```

There's no reason to create an instance there, just use the class name directly:

```
doSomethingWith(TheClass.variable);
```

Java is somewhat interesting in that it allows you to access `static` members via instance references (`instance.variable`), but the normal way to access them is through the class (`TheClass.variable`).

Also, if your `static` members aren't `final`, you can get some *very* confusing-seeming behavior:

```
TheClass a = new TheClass();
a.variable = 1;
TheClass b = new TheClass();
b.variable = 2;
System.out.println(a.variable); // 2?!?!?!
```

So in general, best to avoid accessing `static` members via instance references.

Alternately, make the class a singleton with instance (non-`static`) members instead.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I have learned that direct access to class variables, setting class variables to public is something I should not do, so the three variables are set private, two which are private static final, and one which is just private - there is no direct access. Instead for the regular private variable, methods access and update it, and for the private static final variables methods only use it for reference (checking values, copying one of them to the private as a reset). Only using dosomethingwith(TheObjectName.method), never (theObjectName.variable).